# Dev Express DataGrid cell cannot change a value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, devexpress

The first 3 columns of my datagrid in Dev Express are loaded from a datasource. I have 2 more columns: *AccountID (ID Akun)* and *GridColumn1*, created via datagrid designer and for some reason I can't change their values.

When I type a value in a cell for *AccountID (ID Akun)* or *GridColumn1* columns and then move to another cell, the entered value into the previous cell disappears. Also when I try to create a new column again then always have the same result that the column cell gets empty.

How do I create a column? I simply use the designer page and then click on `Add Column` icon.

Below is the screenshot.
[image]

What could possibly go wrong and provoke the empty cell behaviour?

Note that I have no any `changeValue` or `click` cell event configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution.

The problem was in the datasource class. I have a class named *"SalaryType"* that does not have the *"AccountID"* property, so when loading the datasource from  *"SalaryType"* class, it is not able to edit a column which does not come from the *"SalaryType"* class.

To fix it, I added the *"AccountID"* property and defined `get` & `set` methods to access and update its value. And the cell editing works now.